# Compare two values with php, highlight the highest

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to highlight the winner in a basketball game by comparing the scores of two team, and highlighting the winner (highest score) team, by adding a class "winner" to the HTML element like this:

```
<ul class="game-result">
   <li class="winner"><span>Team 1</span><?php echo $team1_points; ?></li>
   <li class=""><span>Team 2</span><?php echo $team2_points; ?></li>
</ul>
```

I'm using wordpress and php, any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Like so

```
<ul class="game-result">
<li <?php echo (($team1_points>$team2_points)?'class="winner"':''); ?>><span>Team 1</span><?php echo $team1_points; ?></li>
<li <?php echo (($team2_points>$team1_points)?'class="winner"':''); ?>><span>Team 2</span><?php echo $team2_points; ?></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="game-result">
  <li <?=($team1_points > $team2_points ? "class='winner'" : "")?> ><span>Team 1</span><?php echo $team1_points; ?></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="game-result">
     <li <?php echo (($team1_points>$team2_points)?'class="winner"':'class=""'); ?>><span>Team 1</span><?php echo $team1_points; ?></li>
     <li <?php echo (($team2_points>$team1_points)?'class="winner"':'class=""'); ?>><span>Team 2</span><?php echo $team2_points; ?></li>
</ul>
```

Even though Flyer's answer is correct, this one will make your code look *exactly* as you posted it in the question description.